# Как программно изменять задержку анимации?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Вот код

```
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.alpha_appear);
    introducingText.startAnimation(animation);
    animation.setStartOffset(1000);
    hello.startAnimation(animation);
    animation.setStartOffset(2000);
    understoodBut.startAnimation(animation);
```

Почему-то все анимации начинаются одновременно с задержкой в 2 секунды (2000 мс), хотя сначала ставится одна задержка и начинается анимация, потом другая и т.д.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы сначала анимация применилась к одной `view`, потом  к другой, потом к третьей? Без создания трех разных анимаций с разной задержкой

**alpha_appear.xml**

```
<alpha
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fillBefore="true"
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" >
</alpha>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как альтернативный вариант можно использовать [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) заместо анимации из `xml`.

```
private void startAnimation(View view, long delay){
    ViewCompat.animate(view)
                 .setDuration(2000L)
                 .alphaBy(0f)
                 .alpha(1f)
                 .setStartDelay(delay)
                 .start();
}
```

Применение:

```
startAnimation(introducingText, 0);
startAnimation(hello, 1000);
startAnimation(understoodBut, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы передали объект анимации первой вьюхе, а потом изменить значение его поля. Вот оно и применилось.

Хотите разные анимации для разных вьюх- создавайте для каждой вьюхи отдельный экземпляр анимации

Answer (score 1):

Возможно это происходит из за того что это один и тот же объект у котрого меняется одно и тоже свойство. В любом случае лучше не пользоваться XML анимациями без крайней нужды коей являются сложные состовные анимации а сделать просто используя `ViewPropertyAnimator`.

```
introducingText.animate().alpha(1f).start();
hello.animate().alpha(1f).setStartOffset(1000).start();
understoodBut.animate().alpha(1f).setStartOffset(2000).start();
```